# What is a measure of hardness-of-approximation by samples?

Tags: sampling, terminology, estimators

Suppose there is a large vector $\mathbf{x}$ of real numbers, and I want to estimate a certain aggregate function $f(\mathbf{x})$ by taking a small sample of the population $\mathbf{x}$. I would like to know how many samples I need in order to have a 95% confidence interval of a given size (say 1%). The number of samples probably depends on the function $f$: a larger number indicates that $f$ is "harder to approximate by sampling". What is a term for this number of samples? Where can I find data on which functions $f$ are easier/harder to approximate?

One term that came to my mind is [sample complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_complexity), but from what I see, it is not the same: it measures the number of training samples required to learn a function from a given class of functions. In my case, the function is fixed and given, and I want to know the number of samples required to estimate the function value to a given accuracy.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by an "aggregate function."  Would that be what we normally call a *statistic,* or is it something else?

Comment: @whuber I mean any function that takes as input a vector of values and returns a single value, such as: mean, median, minimum, maximum, geometric mean, etc.

Comment: That's called a "statistic."  The "easier/harder" distinction is an uncommon one because there is no clear way to define it and the more relevant questions usually concern how to obtain data that enable one to estimate $f$ efficiently and how its standard error of estimate varies with the sample size for a given sampling method.

Comment: This question can't be answered unless you can clarify what you mean by "to know f(x) with e.g. 1% accuracy".

Comment: @Eoin I mean a confidence interval of, say, 95% confidence, whose length is 1% of the interval mean. I edited the question.

Comment: "1% of the interval mean" isn't a very good indication, as the interval mean can be negative or very close to zero, which doesn't necessarily mean that we should expect a small interval.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I see. On the other hand, giving an absolute length for the interval may not be very meaningful in settings with units. For example, if I am measuring length, then an interval length of "2" may be very different if it is measured in meters or kilometers.

Comment: How about *sensitivity*?